# Could the .NET Jitter optimise away a While XmlReader.Read loop?

Tags: asp.net, .net, jit, xmlreader

<sub>I asked a separate question (now deleted) for what I thought the actual problem was.</sub>

Could the .NET Jitter not actually execute this loop:

```vb
Private Shared Sub CheckXmlValidity(ByVal textReader As System.IO.StreamReader)
  Try
    ' Check for "interesting" xml documents.
    Dim settings = New System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings()
    settings.XmlResolver = Nothing
    settings.MaxCharactersInDocument = 655360
    ' Successfully parse the file, otherwise an XmlException is to be thrown.
    Dim reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings)
    Try
      While reader.Read()
        'Just checking.
      End While
    Finally
      reader.Close()
    End Try
  Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New HttpException(500, "Invalid Xml data", ex)
  End Try
End Sub
```

I would hope not exactly because of the side-effect of the exceptions that could be thrown, but I'm just checking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JITer, and really any optimizer, can only remove items which have no effect on the execution of the problem.  Proving a method has no effect is very hard to do in .Net.  Particularly because every method call can have an effect if the source object is `null` (it would throw an exception).  Hence even methods are known to be a no-op can't be fully removed without inserting a `null` check of sorts (1)

In this case `XmlReader.Read` is an `abstract` method on an unsealed type which is even harder.  The JITer could only remove this call if it knew that every implementation of  `XmlReader.Read` was a no-op and hence had no effect.  It can't ever know this though because the number of derivations of `XmlReader` is not a fixed set.  A new DLL could be loaded at any time with a new derivation of `XmlReader` which had a meaningful definition and hence couldn't be optimized away.

(1) Note: I'm not saying the JITer does this, just that if it removed the method it would need to do some form of `null` checking.